# Relacionamento entre Recursos Rest com Spring boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou aprendendo *Spring Boot Rest* e com uma dúvida que não consigo resolver sozinha, poderiam me ajudar?

Criei o seguinte mapeamento entre as entidades Lançamento e Pessoa:

Entidade Pessoa:

```
   @Entity
   public class Pessoa {

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa")
    private List<Lancamento> lancamentos;
    //getters setters
    }
```

Entidade Lancamento:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lancamento")
public class Lancamento {
...
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
private Pessoa pessoa;
//getters setters
}
```

Resultado Esperado:

```
{
  "nome":"Pessoa1",
   lancamentos:[
         {
           "id":"1",
           "descricao":"Educacao"
         },
         {
          "id":"2",
          "descricao":"Alimentacao"
         },
       ]
}
```

Resultado Obtido:

```
{
  "nome":"Pessoa1"
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Anna, tenta remover esse anotation @JsonIgnore e testa. Pode ser que isso esteja impedindo(ignorando) esse atributo. Outra coisa. Vc tem todos os getters e setters criados?

Comment: Olá Danilo, quando tiro o @JsonIgnore da erro de dependência circular e na da é retornado na requisição, e criei todos os getters e setters também.

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei a solução no Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue , que me deu o resultado esperado. Basta usar as annotations `@JsonManagedReference` e `@JsonBackReference` do [Jackson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jackson).

O código ficou assim:

Entidade Pessoa:

```
   @Entity
   public class Pessoa {

    ...
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa")
    private List<Lancamento> lancamentos;
    //getters setters
    }
```

Entidade Lancamento:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lancamento")
public class Lancamento {
...
@JsonBackReference
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
private Pessoa pessoa;
//getters setters
   }
```